# problem in my int main when i am passing the values to the function

Tags: c++

The whole program is working its just not showing name after running

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>

using namespace std;

class employee{
    
private:
    char profession;
    int dob,sallery;
    
public:
    int hour;
    
    char names;
    
    
    void display(int hour,char names[20]){
        
        cout<<"thank you "<<names[20]<<"for working for our company\n here is your "<<endl;
        
        if(hour>=8){
            cout<<"for working 7-8 hours you will be payed 1500 Rupees"<<endl;
        }
        else if (hour>=6){
            cout<<"you have worked for 5-6 hours your wage will be 1250 Rupees"<<endl;
        }
        else if(hour>=4){
            cout<<"you have worked for 3-4 hours your wage will be 850 Rupees"<<endl;
        }
        else if(hour>=2){
            cout<<"you have worked for 1-2 hours your wage will be 500 Rupees"<<endl;
        }
        else {
            cout<<"you have entered wrong input"<<endl;
        }
    }
};

int main(){
    
    char x[20];
    int y;
    cout<<"enter your name here"<<endl;
    cin>>x;
    
    cout<<"enter the number of hours you worked"<<endl;
    cin>>y;
    
    employee c1;
    
    c1.display(y,x);

    return 0;
}
```

i am not able to pass the above char from user to the function.

Comment: `cout<<"thank you "<<names[20]` attempts to access a single character at index 20. This exhibits undefined behavior by way of accessing an index out of bounds; valid indexes into an array of 20 elements are 0 through 19. Printing a single character is likely not what you wanted to do here anyway.

Comment: Unless some outside constraint is forcing you to use `char` arrays instead of `std::string`... Just use `std::string`.

Comment: If you are learning C++, I recommend checking your C++ book to see how a variable like `char names[20]` is printed there.  I am certain the book is not suggesting `cout<<names[20]`.

Comment: thank you guys it help me a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to take string as input, better to use string data type.

Instead of

```
char x[20];
int y;
cout<<"enter your name here"<<endl;
cin>>x;
```

Try changing it to

```
string x;
int y;
cout<<"enter your name here"<<endl;
cin>>x;
```

And in your `void display()` function
Change from

```
void display(int hour,char names[20]){
        
cout<<"thank you "<<names[20]<<"for working for our company\n here is your "<<endl;
```

To this

```
void display(int hour,string name){
        
cout<<"thank you "<<name<<"for working for our company\n here is your "<<endl;
```